# MySQL, Get number of last records in second table for each element of first, divided by specific time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables:

case_map

```
case_id | creation_date
________|___________________
49      | 2013-04-30
51      | 2013-05-15
82      | 2014-05-23
109     | 2013-06-01
123     | 2013-07-23
```

case_legend

```
id | case_id | operation_number | operation_date | failure
___|_________|__________________|________________|________
1  | 49      | 105              | 2013-05-03     | 0
2  | 51      | 105              | 2013-05-28     | 0
3  | 51      | 110              | 2013-05-29     | 0
4  | 51      | 115              | 2013-06-02     | 1
5  | 51      | 110              | 2013-06-05     | 0
6  | 82      | 105              | 2013-05-28     | 0
7  | 82      | 110              | 2013-05-30     | 0
8  | 82      | 115              | 2013-06-01     | 0
9  | 82      | 120              | 2013-06-01     | 0
10 | 82      | 125              | 2013-06-02     | 0
11 | 109     | 105              | 2013-06-27     | 0
12 | 123     | 105              | 2013-07-27     | 0
13 | 123     | 110              | 2013-08-10     | 0
```

And I want to know how many cases was recieved and how many of **these** cases are on operation 105 and 125 (**'on operation' = value of operation_number for row with max operation_date for this case_id**) in a certain time interval, for example 'from May, 2013 to Jule, 2013', splited by mounth.

For these purposes, I made ​​the following query:

```
SELECT
            `recieved_cases`.`abbreviated_date`,
            `recieved_cases`.`recieved_count`,
            `operation_105`.`105_count`,
            `operation_125`.`125_count`
        FROM (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `creation_date`, '%Y-%m' ) AS `abbreviated_date`, COUNT( `case_id` ) AS `recieved_count`
            FROM `case_map`
            WHERE `creation_date` BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-07-31'
            GROUP BY `abbreviated_date`
        ) AS `recieved_cases`
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `t1`.`operation_date`, '%Y-%m' ) AS `abbreviated_date`, COUNT( `t1`.`operation_number` ) AS `105_count`
            FROM `case_legend` AS `t1`
            WHERE `t1`.`id` = (
                SELECT `t2`.`id`
                FROM `case_legend` AS `t2`
                WHERE `t2`.`case_id` = `t1`.`case_id`
                ORDER BY `t2`.`operation_date` DESC, `t2`.`id` DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )
            AND `operation_number` = 105
            GROUP BY `abbreviated_date`
        ) AS `operation_105`
        ON `recieved_cases`.`abbreviated_date` = `operation_105`.`abbreviated_date`
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `t1`.`operation_date`, '%Y-%m' ) AS `abbreviated_date`, COUNT( `t1`.`operation_number` ) AS `125_count`
            FROM `case_legend` AS `t1`
            WHERE `t1`.`id` = (
                SELECT `t2`.`id`
                FROM `case_legend` AS `t2`
                WHERE `t2`.`case_id` = `t1`.`case_id`
                ORDER BY `t2`.`operation_date` DESC, `t2`.`id` DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )
            AND `operation_number` = 125
            GROUP BY `abbreviated_date`
        ) AS `operation_125`
        ON `recieved_cases`.`abbreviated_date` = `operation_125`.`abbreviated_date`
        ORDER BY `recieved_cases`.`abbreviated_date`
```

**My problem is** that such a request takes into account also cases with creation_date not in a specified time interval. Ie case, which has the last operation in the specified interval, but was created earlier - is taken into account, and it should not be. How can I fix this query?

Desired result for provided example is:

```
abbreviated_date | recieved_count | 105_count | 125_count
_________________|________________|___________|__________
2013-05          | 2              | 0         | 0
2013-06          | 1              | 1         | 1
2013-07          | 1              | 0         | 0
```

*Can a temporary table helps me here? I mean if I first create table like case_legend with creation_date field. I think on this one for the last hour, but not sure how to do it.*

P.S. Also, if my query is bad and you can give me an advise how to optimize it - I would be grateful.

Comment: What would be your desired result for the sample data you're giving?

Comment: Why isn't 105_count 1 for may for case 49?

Comment: Because case_id 49 was added in Apr, 2013 according to `case_map`.`creation_date`. I want to work with cases, that was added only in specified time interval.

Comment: In your result set, shouldn't 105_count be 1 for 2013-07 ?

Comment: Nope, because for `case_id` = 123 last operation 110, 2013-08, thus we should not take it into account. Basically, all what I trying to display - how many cases was recieved and how many of them ended it story on specific operation for the period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
select year(cm.creation_date), month(cm.creation_date),
       count(distinct case when cl.operation_number = 105 then case_id end) as op105,
       count(distinct case when cl.operation_number = 125 then case_id end) as op125
from case_map cm join
     case_legend cl
     on cm.case_id = cl.case_id
group by year(cm.creation_date), month(cm.creation_date)
order by 1, 2;
```

If not, you can start with the most recent date for each of the operations:

```
select cm.*,
       max(case when cl.operation_number = 105 then operation_date end) as op105,
       max(case when cl.operation_number = 125 then operation_date end) as op125
from case_map cm join
     case_legend cl
     on cm.case_id = cl.case_id
group by cm.case_id;
```

And then work from there.

EDIT:

Now that you supplied the desired results, the query is not too difficult:

```
select date_format(cm.creation_date, '%Y-%m' ) as yyyymm,
       sum(cl.opeartion_number = 105) as op105,
       sum(cl.opeartion_number = 125) as op125
from case_map cm join
     case_legend cl
     on cm.case_id = cl.case_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from case_legend cl2
                  where cl2.case_id = cl.case_id and
                        cl2.operation_date > cl.operation_date
                 )
group by date_format(cm.creation_date, '%Y-%m')
order by 1;
```

So the answer is:  You don't need temporary tables.

Comment: First example, as I understand it, just count cases that have a row with operation number 105 and 125. Thats clearly not what I need. Second example, however, not what I need aswell, because if last operation for case is, lets say, 110 (case_id = 51 in my example) it would count it as op105, do not count it as op125, but it meaningless for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8673a3/9

It gives you the same results but in a different format perhaps, than what you prefer.

```
select 
DATE_FORMAT( operation_date, '%Y-%m' ) as `Date`, 
count(cl.case_id), cl.operation_number,
t.count
from 
case_legend cl
left join case_map cm
on cl.case_id = cm.case_id

left join (
  select 
  DATE_FORMAT( cl.operation_date, '%Y-%m' ) as `Date`, count(cl.case_id) as `count`, 'All'     as operation_number
  from 
  case_legend cl
  left join case_map cm
  on cl.case_id = cm.case_id
  where operation_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-07-31'
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( operation_date, '%Y-%m' )

  ) t

on t.Date = DATE_FORMAT( operation_date, '%Y-%m' )

where cl.operation_number in (105, 125)
and operation_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-07-31'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( operation_date, '%Y-%m' ), cl.operation_number
;
```